# How to return blob url after http request inside function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make simple chat application. I get messages from service, and ngFor in template print the messages. When I have message image type, I want to get blob from server and return url to image src.

This is what I have

***HTML Template***

```
<div class="row message_chat_row" *ngFor="let chatMessage of chatMessages | async">
    <div class="col chat_message_outer align-self-center">
        <div class="row" [ngClass]="getChatMessageRowClass(chatMessage.sender_type)">

<div *ngIf="chatMessage.type === 'text' || chatMessage.type === 'info'" [innerHTML]="chatMessage.value" class="conpeek_chat_message_inner"></div>

<div *ngIf="chatMessage.type === 'image'" class="chat_message_inner">
                <a (click)="downloadImg()"><img [src]="getImageSrc(chatMessage.value)"></a>
            </div>

<div *ngIf="chatMessage.type === 'file'" class="chat_message_inner">
                <a (click)="downloadFile()">{{chatMessage.filename}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Chat Component***

```
getImageSrc(img_url) {
    console.log('GET IMGAGE SRC', img_url);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': $c.params.token
    });

    let result; 

    this.httpClient.get(img_url, {
        responseType: "blob",
        headers: headers
      }).subscribe(res => {
        result = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      });

    return result;
  }
```

What should I do in this situation ? I want to return result after request is done.

Comment: Return the observable - `return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(map((res) => URL.createObjectURL(res)))`

Comment: This method return object to template in this case. I change ```map(res => URL.createObjectURL(res))``` to ```map(res => 'test')``` and it still return object

Comment: It returns an *observable*, you'll need to resolve it

Comment: @jonrsharpe could You give some example please ? I do not know how to do this in this case :/

Comment: They cover that in the tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: I can't see example like my one. The function return me a object, but I need a value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198587/discussion-between-storin-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 0):

Your request is asynchronous. In this case you return `result` before its assignation in your get request.

Regarding your issue, you could try something like this:

```js
getImageSrc(img_url): Observable<any> {
  console.log('GET IMGAGE SRC', img_url);

  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': $c.params.token
  });

  return this.httpClient.get(img_url, {
    responseType: "blob",
    headers: headers
  }).pipe(
    map(res => URL.createObjectURL(res))
  );
}
```

That way, you return an observable and can subscribe to it wherever you want.

Comment: This method return object to template in this case. I change ```map(res => URL.createObjectURL(res))``` to ```map(res => 'test')``` and it still return object.

Comment: Yes. It returns an `Observable`, which is an object. You can then `subscribe` to this observable like `getImageSrc('url').subscribe(image => /* Do something with your value */`. the point being that you are no longer limited to the `getImageSrc` method body to do something with the value. (Plus, it being asynchronous can have advantages too)