# How to get value from Observable function in template - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I want get Blob object from request in observable function during *ngFor loop. I have a small chat app which gets data from a service and prints it in the view. One kind of the messages are images. When I try to get the Blob from the server, the function returned to my `null` (if I use async in template) or `[object Object]` if I do not use async. How to return this data properly?

I use Angular 8

***HTML Template***

```
<div class="row message_chat_row" *ngFor="let chatMessage of chatMessages | async">
    <div class="col chat_message_outer align-self-center">
        <div class="row" [ngClass]="getChatMessageRowClass(chatMessage.sender_type)">
            
<div *ngIf="chatMessage.type === 'text' || chatMessage.type === 'info'" [innerHTML]="chatMessage.value" class="conpeek_chat_message_inner"></div>
            
<div *ngIf="chatMessage.type === 'image'" class="chat_message_inner">
                <a (click)="downloadImg()"><img [src]="getImageSrc(chatMessage.value)"></a>
            </div>
            
<div *ngIf="chatMessage.type === 'file'" class="chat_message_inner">
                <a (click)="downloadFile()">{{chatMessage.filename}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Chat Component***

```
getImageSrc(img_url):Observable<any> {
    console.log('GET IMGAGE SRC', img_url);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': $c.params.token
    });
    

    return this.httpClient.get(img_url, {
      responseType: "blob",
      headers: headers
    }).pipe(
      map(res => URL.createObjectURL(res))
    );
  }
```

Comment: This is [*still*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690182/how-to-return-blob-url-after-http-request-inside-function-in-angular#comment101827378_57690182) covered in the tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial.

Comment: that was mistake while copying. I edited the post

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't find the solution there, there is no example to use the observable function and get data from there

Comment: not related, but you should rethink: `<img [src]="getImageSrc(chatMessage.value)">` anyway. This is called on each change detection and since it's a http-request inside ngFor, I would assume it will just kill your browser.

Comment: @AJT_82 that is true, it could help me to resolve me this problem too. Thank You !

Comment: There are absolutely examples of that; I'd recommend running through the whole tutorial at least once, it covers a lot of useful concepts.

Comment: The `async` pipe should work. Does the server return anything?

Comment: Yes, it return proper Blob object, I take this code to service and in subscribe function I update the message and it works. I can see the image.